# How to select and scroll to new Row in Datagridview?

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to a DB Table.
The DataGridView is not editable, there are some text fields where the data can be edited, which is controlled with buttons.
I have a NewRow Button with the following code:

```
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Selected)
            { row.Selected = false; }
        } 
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.NewRowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Wat I need is:

- the datagridview should scroll to the bottom (where the newRow is)
- the newRow should be focused, so that the textfields show the new (empty) row (content)

I've tried:

```
        bindSourceGS.Position = dataGridView1.NewRowIndex;
```

but that doesn't select the datagridview's newRow.
I want to use the datagridview's newRow because when user presses cancel button I don't have to delete the row in the Dataset and the datagridview.Rows[i] has a IsNewRow Property.

Comment: don't mix DataGrid and DataGridView, they're different controls. I edited your question to make it clear you're using a DataGridView

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If its *Winform* then you can use this

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
```

and set the `datagridview.CurrentCell` to your new row cell address.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it's Winform, your suggestions both work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note: For FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to succeed if you have mixed-hieght rows, you need to ensure that Row Template height is at least as great at the last row height. This is rather a problem since I find one cannot set any row height greater than the Row Template height.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this problem and found that setting `dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.count-1` works well as long as the `AutoSizeRowsMode` property is NOT set to `DisplayedCells`.

If you have problems with setting `dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex=dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1` and the grid not scrolling to bottom try setting the `AutosizeRowsMode` property to `AllCells`.